# AngularJs text input field regular expression

Tags: regex, ng-pattern

Currently, I use the following expression for my ngPattern attribute: `/[^*]/` meaning that any input is allowed but it has to contain at least one char different from *. Now, additional requirement arose - the input has to be numeric only.

Is there any possibility to combine these two requirements in one single regular expression? I just can't get it... Or should I move the condition check to my controller, where I would apply two regular expressions consecutively, programmatically.

Comment: uh, doesn't "numeric only" kinda make the first requirement obsolete? (a digit isn't an asterisk)

Comment: So, Женя, try `/[0-9]/` or `/[^0-9]/` depending on your code.

Comment: Hello, the asterix is allowed! But the input is not allowed to consist of * only. So: "\*" ist not allowed but "ppp\*ppp" is. Therefore /[0-9]/ or /[^0-9]/ would not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I asked a colleague of mine today. Here is the right solution: `/[\d*]*\d[\d*]*/`

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the input to be numeric, but * is also allowed? If so, this will do the trick:

```
<input type="text" ng-pattern="[1-9\*]*">
```

In general, you can do most stuff in regex, so there is no need to take it to the controller.

Comment: That wouldn't work for me :-) \* is allowed but it is not allowed to be the only type of char in the input. * or **** or ******** are not allowed. But abcd\*fgh or abcd\*\*\*\*fdh are allowed. Therefore I used /[^*]/ before.